# Can script task able to call send mail task wizard by using inside code?

Tags: c#, ssis

I have a requirement that, needs to validate the flat file. The validation part is doing by using script task, but for every validate I need to send both passes/fail status to the mail, I have multiple validations. I know that could be done using `System.Net.Mail` namespace functionality. Before that, I want to ensure whether it can possible through call "Send email task" wizard or not. I  have only 1-month experience in SSIS if anyone suggests me it will help me. validation like below

```cs
string a; String a1; String a2;

if(a != null)
{
    send mail......value;
}
else
{
    send mail ........fail no value..;
}

if(a1 != null)
{
    send mail......value;
}
else
{
    send mail ........fail no value..;
}

if(a2 != null)
{
    send mail.....value;
}
else
{
    send mail ........fail no value..;
}
```

Comment: Your best way is to use the SendMail in your c# code.

Comment: I achieved this by using the Event handlers. I had created one Readwrite variable in the script component, Stored the required string value is based on the conditions. This variable will call from Send mail task which is presented in the Event Handler.
Note: The variable must be put in the Postexecute() function